# Terraform and docker networking

Tags: networking, docker, terraform

I have defined a terraform recipe with a docker provisioner like this:

```
provider "docker" {
    host = "tcp://127.0.0.1:2375/"
}

# Create the network
resource "docker_network" "private_network" {
    name = "${var.customer_name}_network"
}

resource "docker_container" "goagent" {
    image = "${docker_image.goagent.latest}"
    name = "${var.customer_name}_goagent"
    command = [ "/bin/sh", "-c", "/usr/bin/supervisord" ]
    network_mode = "bridge"
    networks = [ "${docker_network.private_network.name}" ]
    hostname = "${var.customer_name}_goagent"
}

resource "docker_image" "goagent" {
    name = "local/goagent"
}
```

I would expect that the container will be connected just to the network created on the fly (using the variable customer_name).
But what I see is that the container gets connected also to the default bridge network (172.17.0.0/16), so it gets connected to two networks.

Is there a way to configure the container in terraform in a way that it gets connected only to the network I specify in the networks list?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this is an unresolved [bug](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-docker/issues/10) as of 0.10.8